# Disabling the JIT and execution time

Tags: java, bash, statistics

I'm trying to make a (very, very, simplified) statistical study of the performance for the JIT compiler in the JVM for a class project on statistics. To do so, I've made a simple algorithm that sorts random vectors using a common algorithm (mergesort), and outputs the execution time in nanoseconds (using system.nanoTime(), probably misspelled), and a bash script which alternates between using jit and not using it. The first time I ran it I obtained quite expectable results, execution with jit was 3x times faster approximately, but I've ran it multiple times before and the result (with the very same jar file and script) was completely different. Surprisingly, in following runs of the script the times with the JIT on were slightly higher, meaning the program was running slower with the JIT, but not significantly.

I wouldn't be that surprised about the results I'm getting if I hadn't got that first result, as with such a short program maybe the JIT doesn't even have time to do some of its optimisations, and rather adds a little overhead to the cost, but augmenting the size of the vector or the number of vectors to sort (to numbers like 10000 or 20000) isn't changing anything.

I'm starting to think I'm not disabling the jit correctly, I have to say I got more than once the expected (faster JIT) results, but I mostly get the other values when executing the program. The script I'm using is quite simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=0

#Clear the output files
echo "TIME WITH JIT" > file_jit.out
echo "TIME WITHOUT JIT" > file_nojit.out

#Generate data
while [  $COUNTER -lt $1 ]; do
    echo "$COUNTER of $1 run data."
    #----------THOSE ARE THE TWO IMPORTANT LINES-----------
    java -jar SortTime.jar >> file_jit.out
    java -Xint -jar SortTime.jar >> file_nojit.out
    #------------------------------------------------------
COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+1))  
done
```

As you can see I'm using the -Xint option to force interpreted mode (disable JIT). I've also tried Djava.compiler=NONE with the exact same result so I chose this one because it's more compact.

That's the output of my java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

As you might have seen I'm using linux, ubuntu 13.04(64bit) and the laptop I'm using has an AMD  E1-1200 dual core processor (1.4Ghz), and 8GB of RAM.

Any sollutions/workarounds would be much appreciated, note that I'm not trying at any time to do a precise study about Java's JIT efficiency but trying to do a class exercise on how to manage statistical data related to the software world, so comments of the validity of my study are not relevant.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you measure the time? And what *exact* results do you get? 10000 doesn’t sound very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your program with `-Xint` guarantees that none of the methods are compiled.  Running in default mode, however, does not guarantee that `any` of your functions (e.g mergesort) will be JIT'ed.

> I'm trying to make a (very, very, simplified) statistical study of the
>   performance for the JIT compiler

This is not as easy as it sounds.  The JVM is not deterministic, and there are other factors at play like Garbage Collection that may affect your results.

One thing you might try is running with `-XX:+PrintCompilation` to see if your method is even being JIT'ed.  Hotspot will only compile methods that are repeatedly invoked.

Comment: It seems the program was running too fast (not so much function calls), changing the vector size to 200000 printed output for the recursive mergesort function being compiled by the JIT, so it seems that might be causing the trouble, I'll update later with what I've got, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

JVM does not always perform JIT even if JIT is enabled. JIT (= compiling Java byte codes into native codes at runtime) has non-negligible cost, so JVM performs JIT only when it expects that the compilation overhead can be offset by performance gain from native code. Simply saying, JVM performs JIT when it expects that the target Java byte codes will be executed repeatedly many times.

So, if you want to compare the performance between JIT and interpreter, you have to make sure that JIT compilation is performed. My suggestion is: **Do many loops BEFORE starting to measure performance in order to make sure JIT is performed.**

```
// Virtual code.

// Urge the JVM to perform JIT for doSomething.
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    doSomething();
}

// Then, measure the performance.
long startTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    doSomething();
}
long endTImestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```